# Databricks/Spark read custom metadata from Parquet file

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I created a Parquet file with custom metadata at file level:
[image: data = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet(path)]

Now I'm trying to read that metadata from the Parquet file in (Azure) Databricks. But when I run the following code I don't get any metadata which is present there.

```
storageaccount = 'zzzzzz'
containername = 'yyyyy'
access_key = 'xxxx'
spark.conf.set(f'fs.azure.account.key.{storageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net', access_key)

path = f"wasbs://{containername}@{storageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net/generated_example_10m.parquet"
data = spark.read.format('parquet').load(path)
print(data.printSchema())
```

Comment: How did you create the dummy Parquet content and metadata ? was it with spark or some other tools ?

Comment: AFAIK Spark doesn't have such capability, associated JIRA  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10803 was simply closed :(

Comment: I created the parquet file in Python using PyArrow. Simply by creating a list of metadata values and adding that to the schema

Comment: Thank you mazaneicha, that seems to be exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

**I try to reproduce same thing in my environment. I got this output.**

Please follow below code and Use **select("*", "_metadata")**

```
path = "wasbs://<container>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<file_path>.parquet"
data = spark.read.format('parquet').load(path).select("*", "_metadata")
display(data)
```

**or**

Mention your schema and load path with `.select("*", "_metadata")`

```
df = spark.read \
  .format("parquet") \
  .schema(schema) \
  .load(path) \
  .select("*", "_metadata")

display(df)
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to give me only the metadata on column level, but not on file/schema metadata.

Comment: hi @Korenaga, unfortunately file/schema metadata not possible in databricks. you can try with ADF.